# No overload for method 'GetActiveInstructors' takes 2 arguments

Tags: .net, entity-framework, arguments, overloading

I am trying to have a repeater that is populated through the names entered into the text files that are associated with this button. However, when I click on the button I get the following error.

Code:

```
protected void btnInsName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            var wingsList = context.Wings.Where(row => row.Enabled == 1).ToList();

            DataTable dtDDL = new DataTable();

            dtDDL = ConvertToDTForWings(wingsList);
            ddlWing.DataSource = dtDDL;
            ddlWing.DataBind();

            var result = context.GetActiveInstructors(txtLastName.Text, txtFirstName.Text).ToList();

            dt =ConvertToDTForInstructors(result);

            rptInsReport.DataSource = dt;

            rptInsReport.DataBind();

            ViewState["ReportDataSource"] = dt;

            if (result.Count != 0)
            {
                PrintButtons("YES");
            }
            else
            {
                PrintButtons("NO");
            }
        }
        catch (EntityException ex)
        {
            NtfyObject.ServerError(Page);
        }

        rptInsReport.Visible = true;
    }
```

Error:  No overload for method 'GetActiveInstructors' takes 2 arguments

Comment: What is unclear about that error message?

Comment: Where is your method "GetActiveInstructors" defined?

Comment: I apologize flr the lack of information. I was in a hurry when making this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by the exception, your method `GetActiveInstructors` does not expect two arguments.

Therefore the exception is caused by this line:

```
var result = context.GetActiveInstructors(txtLastName.Text, txtFirstName.Text).ToList();
```

Please look at the definition of `GetActiveInstructors`. Does it expect both a first name and last name, as separate arguments? You either provided an extra argument, or too few arguments.